# Save images using Pillow without overwriting already saved images

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to save around 12000 images generated from a particular code. I will be able to save these images only using my Project VPN which keeps disconnecting some times and then the entire process of saving takes place by overwriting already saved images and taking again a lot of time.

How do I avoid this?

```py
from PIL import Image
dirc = os.path.join(r"C:\\", "DATASET", "Images", f"{measurename}")
if not os.path.exists(dirc):
    os.makedirs(dirc)
    gray_image_cropped.save(os.path.join(dirc, f"{id}_seg{obj}.tif"))
```

Comment: Don't save the image if the file `os.path.join(dirc, f"{id}_seg{obj}.tif")` already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file exists:

```
from PIL import Image
dirc = os.path.join(r"C:\\", "DATASET", "Images", f"{measurename}")

if not os.path.exists(dirc):
    os.makedirs(dirc)

outfile = os.path.join(dirc, f"{id}_seg{obj}.tif"

if not os.path.exists(outfile):
    gray_image_cropped.save(outfile))
```